# sort records in a descending order with apps-script range.sort() issue

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking to sort some records on a sheet via app-script, but I get this error when using range.sort({column: 1, ascending: false});

What am'I missing?

TypeError: [object Object] is not a function, it is object. (line 6, file "MenuGS")

```
   function sort() {
       var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1tdfsdfsdbfXMg6wmE7oFG2reA2yt_YTf7IRG').getSheetByName('Sugestions');
       var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(3, 1,lastRow-2,11).getDisplayValues();
       range.sort({column: 1, ascending: false}); // I'm trying to sort column A in a decending order
  logger.log(range)
}
```

Comment: It sorts ranges not  arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function sort() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1tdfsdfsdbfXMg6wmE7oFG2reA2yt_YTf7IRG').getSheetByName('Sugestions');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(3, 1,lastRow-2,11);
  range.sort({column: 1, ascending: false}); // I'm trying to sort column A in a decending order
}
```

Comment: I see, I think that I understand. Thank you.